# TableAdapter.Update don't update

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview, tableadapter

I tried to add data from data set to access database with TableAdapter.Update() method, but it doesn't function. Here is my code. I have DataGridView on my Windows Form, Table (Users) are binding to DataGridView.

```
private void btnScanGroups_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    foreach (UserGroup group in g)
    {
        string groupName = group.Name;              
        string groupID = group.Link;
        int userID = 1;
        groupsTableAdapter.InsertGroupsQuery(groupName, groupID, userID);

        text = text+"\n added "+groupName + " - " + groupID;

        richTxtBoxStatus.Text = text;   
    }

    groupsTableAdapter.Fill(facebookGroupAutoPostDBDataSet.Groups);
    groupsBindingSource.EndEdit();
    groupsTableAdapter.Update(facebookGroupAutoPostDBDataSet.Groups);
}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't change anything between `Fill` and `Update`.

Comment: I thought that .Fill() add data to DataSet, .Update() add from DataSet to DB

Comment: Update performs the necessary SQL to apply any changes to the DataSet. If there are no changes, nothing happens. When  you fill a dataset all the rows are unchanged or unmodified.

Comment: so how to add data from data set to DB?

Comment: I think you are expecting your loop to be making pending changes but `InsertGroupsQuery` is already executing against the database.

Comment: Is `InsertGroupsQuery` not doing an insert?

Comment: Here is SQL Statement for 'InserGroupQuery' 'INSERT INTO' `Groups` (`groupName`, `groupID`, `userID`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142388/discussion-between-crowcoder-and-mionis).